# Mark checkboxes in rendered HTML

Tags: jquery, python, django

I've following scenario:

- The user loads `home.html`, selects a subset of the five checkboxes and clicks on submit.
- The user lands on `stats.html`, which will show values related to the selected checkboxes AND marks the specific checkboxes as CHECKED.

I'm passing a variable called 'itemsToCheck' with following content to the `stats.html` template:

```
[(u'8', u'on'), (u'7', u'on')]
```

Where those values should help me to select specific checkboxes like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" checked="yes" name="{{ MyModel.id }}"/>
```

How would you accomplish that (using a template syntax like `checked={% something %}` or maybe jQuery)?

I'm a Django/web development beginner, so please let me know if my approach is completely wrong and if there is a cleaner/more elegant solution.

Comment: You should definitely try to use [Django forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/forms/) to get those kind of things taken care of automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work if you pass the a dict instead of a list:

```
itemsToCheck = {7: 'on', 8: 'on'}

<input type="checkbox" {% if MyModel.id in itemsToCheck.keys %}checked="checked"{% endif %} name="{{ MyModel.id }}"/>
```

For the described list:

```
[(8, 'on'), (9, 'on')]
```

you'll have to do some more processing.

EDIT:
Or in case when dict keys are strings:

```
{% if MyModel.id|stringformat:"s" in itemsToCheck.keys %}
```

Or just prepare the itemsToCheck in a format to skip the conversion...

EDIT 2:
Actually, I'd use a tag here:

```
@register.inclusion_tag('checkbox.html')
def my_checkboxes(request, items):
    return {"items": [{'id': i.id, 'checked': request.POST[str(i.id)] == 'on'} for i in items]}
```

and then in checkbox.html:

```
{% for i in items %}
<input type="checkbox" {% if i.checked %}checked="checked"{% endif %} name="{{ i.id }}"/>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: That was fast, thanks. How would you create a dict from this: 
itemsToCheck = [(k, v) for k, v in request.POST.items() if v == 'on']

Comment: @Josephjun.Melettukunnel `items_to_check_dict = dict(itemsToCheck)`

Comment: @Josephjun.Melettukunnel: you don't need that conversion. Just use the Request instance.

Comment: I just tried this. itemsToCheck = {'7': u'on', '6': u'on'}, {% if MyModel.id in itemsToCheck.keys %}checked="checked"{% endif %}. Unfortunately it doesn't work.

Comment: ... actually, you can use request directly, but will need some modifications in code.. The conversion above will work just fine

Comment: It won't work as model.id is int, while keys are strings... Just try {% if MyModel.id|stringformat:"s" in itemsToCheck.keys %}. But a form will do a better job, as suggested above. Or in your code - itemsToCheck = [(str(k), v) for k, v....]

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was the missing part :-) It's working perfectly now.